# Storing String and Int in a dictionary in swift

Tags: json, swift, uitableview, dictionary

I'm almost new to Swift. [In this URL](http://app.avatejaratsaba1.com/api/Values/GetBaseData) I'll get some element; one of elements is categoryList which has two elements itself. I set the goodTypeName as the table's cell title, and when a cell is pressed it needs to send the goodType which is number (Int) to be placed in the next Url. I tried to create a dictionary but I failed!

UiTable code :::

```
override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return Global.GlobalVariable.names.count
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    if Global.GlobalVariable.names == []
    {
        self.DisplayMessage(UserMessage: "nothing is available ")
        print("server is nil")
    }
    let cell = UITableViewCell()
    let content = Global.GlobalVariable.names[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.text = content
    cell.accessoryType = .disclosureIndicator
    return cell
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    print(indexPath.item)
    let next = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "SVC")
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(next!, animated: true)
}
```

My problem is not with populating them in a table, my problem is when a cell is selected , goodtype is needed to be sent to next page, becuase next page's url has to have the goodtype code.

Comment: the description with the code are misleading add what you have tried so far and elaborate

Comment: I updated the description

Answer (score 1):

You can use the "prepareSegue" to pass Data.

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

```
if segue.identifier == "something"{
    if let startViewController = segue.destination as? StartViewController{
        startViewController.goodtype = Global.GlobalVariable.goodtype[indexPath.row]
    }
}
}
```

And in your StartViewController just assign a variable to receive your data :

```
var goodtype = String()
```

**Or** use the navigation controller but with this line you can access to the another view controller property.

```
         if let startViewController = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "StartViewController") as? StartViewController {
    startViewController.goodtype = Global.GlobalVariable.goodtype[indexPath.row]
     let navigationController = UINavigationController()
  navigationController.pushViewController(startViewController, animated: true)
    }
```

Comment: my problem is not the passing data, my problem is that i cant't recognize each cell goodType! I myself think i need a dictionary

Comment: ok Where is the goodtype stored ? you can also use a class or struct or a dict 
and then with the indexpath.row just select the item which cell is selected.

Comment: i have a global variable that i'm going to store them there ! if that's possible for you please check the url in postman to understand what i mean!  i'm confused with my question too:|

Comment: struct mycalss {
    var goodtype = Int()
    var goodTypeName = String()
}

var mydata = [mycalss]()

var myclass = mycalss.init(goodtype: 101, goodTypeName: "کنجاله سوي")

mydata.append(myclass)

mydata[0].goodTypeName
mydata[0].goodtype

You have many options this is the quickest, 
just create a struct and the create a array of the struct, append the data to your struct and then you can assign it with indexpath.row your data

Comment: how should i set  "   var myclass = mycalss.init(goodtype: 101, goodTypeName: "کنجاله سوي")   " when a cell is selected

Comment: no you have to do this when you are calling your api and feed your data into the table. 
Just insert your response to the struct and then you can have access to it 
for example in viewdidload

Comment: i think there is misunderstanding !! i have already set cell's title, i wanna add a function when one of the cells selected , opens a new view controller, each cell has a different goodtypename and goodtype ! in the next viewcontroller the goodtype which has received from the previous view controller should be set in the URL to load another tabel

Comment: in your didSelect use : let cell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as UITableViewCell
and then cell.goodtype is your selected goodtype ???

Comment: this is it, and  when that cell is selected i need the goodtype instead of goodtypename!!

Comment: i myself think that i need a dictionary which has one Int and One String , and whenever the cell(String) selected , it return the number(Int)